# break json into chunks error of object as it does not understand

Tags: json

When i am trying to load json data from a url and convert into html table. There is a location column which giver error object object and does not reflect the latitude and longitude. All i need to do is break it and using strin concat display lati and longi.

```
   <script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://abcdefghijk.com ",
      //force to handle it as text
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {

      //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
      //and pass downloaded data
      var json = $.parseJSON(data);
      //now json variable contains data in json format
      //let's display a few items

      // we'll put all our html in here for now
      var html = '';
      for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
      {
      // if on first loop, create the col headers  style="position: fixed; min-width: 100px; width:100%;"
      if(i===0)
      {
            html += '<thead><tr>';
            $.each(json[i], function(key, value){
            html += '<th style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;                 background-color: #6F5091;">'+key+'</th>' ;
            });
            //html += '</thead></tr>';
        }

      // loop through all the json objects and for every key add a column with the value
            html += '<tr>';
            $.each(json[i], function(key, value)
            {
               if(key=='location')
               {
               var resultJSON = value;
                html += '<td>'+resultJSON+'</td>' ;
                var data = JSON.parse(resultJSON);
                for (var key in data)
                {
                //console.log(key + ' : ' + data[key]);
                //   alert(key + ' --> ' + data[key]);
                //}
                }
                else
                {
                   html += '<td>'+value+'</td>' ;
                }
            });
        html += '</tr>';
        }
        // push all the html in one go to the page
        $('#results').append(html);
      }
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: _"which giver error object object"_ - that is not an error, it is simply what happens when you try to convert an object into a string value. You need to access the scalar properties of that object, and output them individually. If you are unsure about the structure of the object, log it to console and inspect it there.

Comment: Where in your code is this actually happening? It also looks to me like you're trying to parse it twice - once with `$.parseJSON()` at the top, then again with `JSON.parse()` at the bottom. You only need to parse it once.